# JavaScript check if page contain a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, dom

I created a JavaScript which inserted into the head tag of any web page that I handled, should take care to verify whether or not that page contains a form element and if so, give me back the value of the id and name parameter.

```
//Check if page contain a form
var elementF =  document.getElementsByTagName('form');
var txt = "";
for (var i=0; i<elementF.length; i++)
    {
  txt = txt + elementF.elements[i].value + "<br>";
    }
console.log("ElementF: "+txt);
```

I tested the code both in pages conteining or not containing form elements, but the result is always the same:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

How can I check if a form element is present or not??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Dalorzo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1959948/dalorzo) said in his answer, you can use jQuery like this:

```
$('form')
```

Alternatively, you can use `querySelectorAll`:

```
document.querySelectorAll('form');
```

Comment: with document.querySelectorAll('form'); console return: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function –

Comment: What are your browser/version?

Comment: Are you sure that the error comes from the `document.querySelectorAll` call ?

Comment: now console write: ElementF: [object NodeList]  but how can i view id and name of the form/s?

Comment: Oh okay it's an array like object, which means you can traverse it with a classic for loop, it has a length property.

Answer (score 3):

How about using JQuery with a simple `$("form")`

The pure javascript version of that will be using `querySelectorAll` like:

`document.querySelectorAll("form")`

Comment: I preferred to use javascript if possible

Comment: @almal jquery is among your tags btw

Answer (score 1):

If, by chance, you need to support IE < 8, you can use

```
document.getElementsByTagName("form").length > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

just a simple example of a function you could use. make sure it's called inside the "document ready" function:

```
function getForm()
{
    if($("form").length) 
        return $("form");
    else
        return false;
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
    var my_form = getForm();
    if(my_form !== false) 
        alert("found form with the id: " + my_form.prop("id"));
    else
        alert("no form found");
});
```